# How to implement time tolerance in SQL for general data within a column?

Tags: postgresql

**SUMMARY:** I have two data tables: table1 and table2. I want to join them in the following way:
- a unique id value that is the same within both tables
- ALSO, there is a time value in both tables that I need to be within a certain vicinity of one another (e.g. 30 seconds)
- However, the data in both tables is within YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS form

I have tried to do the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 AS t1

LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
AND t2.message_time BETWEEN t1.time + INTERVAL '20 seconds' AND t1.time - INTERVAL '20 seconds'
```

but it keeps printing out the same row over and over again when I am looping through the result in psycopg2. Is there a better way to do this? Is the query referring to the respective t1.properly?

Comment: You may have a syntax error: Instead of `- time '20 s'`-> `- interval '20 s'`

Comment: @S-Man - thanks for pointing that out. In my actual code, I had it the correct way round, but I just copied it out incorrectly.

Comment: Also, is there any way to find out why my question was down voted? I had an error in the code, but it was just a minor error. Also, I could copy out my python code for using psycopg2, but I can't see the point in that as that is correct. I am not directing this towards anyone in particular, but just wanted to know in general.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the most important word: It's NOT mine :D

Comment: @S-Man - apologies

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch the `BETWEEN` parameters:

```
BETWEEN smaller_value AND greater_value
```

So your join condition needs to be:

```
ON t1.id = t2.id 
    AND t2.message_time BETWEEN t1.message_time - interval '20 seconds' AND t1.message_time + interval '20 seconds'
```

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=cbb25a045bb4991b25a9576d38764f15)

Comment: thanks for your response. I have looked at your db fiddle demonstration and that is exactly the sort of thing I want to do, but it isn't working for me.

Comment: Ok, try to reproduce your problem in the fiddle!